# -ms-transform won't work on table header group (thead) in IE10 (and below, presumably)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Can anyone help me find a way to get -ms-transform working on a table header? The context is that I'm repositioning the header (with Javascript and a CSS transform) to make it stick to the top of the screen when a user has scrolled down to the point that the header would otherwise no longer be visible (and the use rmay not be able to read or understand the data as well without visible column headers).

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aYtVP/2/) (without the Javascript), but I'll post the code here as well:

```
<style>
body { background-color: gray; padding: 0; margin: 0;}        
#move-table { 
    transform: translate(10px, 10px);
    -ms-transform: translate(10px, 10px); 
    -webkit-transform: translate(10px, 10px); 
    -o-transform: translate(10px, 10px); 
    -moz-transform: translate(10px, 10px); 
    background-color: green;
}
#move-thead { 
    transform: translate(10px, 10px);
    -ms-transform: translate(10px, 10px); 
    -webkit-transform: translate(10px, 10px); 
    -o-transform: translate(10px, 10px); 
    -moz-transform: translate(10px, 10px); 
    background-color: red; 
}
</style>

<table width="400" id="move-table">
    <thead id="move-thead">
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Opera, but unsurprisingly Internet Explorer (version 10, but presumably 9 as well) won't play nice. I'll admit it may not make a lot of sense to be repositioning a table header, but if the other browsers don't mind (thankfully), then perhaps there's a workaround for IE?

Comment: For some reason you need to add `display: block;` to `#move-thead {..}`. Then [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/kT4ju/1/).

Comment: It does, but then it will no longer be a table header.

Comment: Then what is it instead?

Comment: A block-level element. If you add a couple of columns to both rows, you'll see that, with display: block; on #move-thead, the header no longer spans across the top of the table.

Comment: [Standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#TermTransformableElement) says a transformable element should be a block-level element. Looks like other browsers are applying standard in a different way, though IE can easily translate spans too ; ).

Comment: It continues, "or whose ‘display’ property computes to ‘table-row’, ‘table-row-group’, ‘table-header-group’, ‘table-footer-group’, ‘table-cell’, or ‘table-caption’".

Comment: Yes it does, I also tested those, but unfortenately they didn't work in IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the transform does work on individual table cells, so I managed to fix this by applying `-ms-transform` specifically to all the `td`-children of `thead`, rather than the header itself.

In the simplified example used in the question, all it would take, then, is to add this:

```
#move-thead td {
    -ms-transform: translate(10px, 10px);
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aYtVP/3/). My header now scrolls along happily in IE, too.

Answer (score 2):

After playing with many settings in IE and getting nowhere I decided to do a very small amount of research and discovered that IE stopped working with pure css sticky tables about 4 years ago.

However, there is a solution which can be found at http://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/

This uses jquery but achieves exactly what you seem to be asking and looks like a more long term solution to your problem.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: just for clarification IE 8,9,10 & maybe 7 do not support the css method given in the question

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I appreciate it. However, I don't use jQuery because it's generally much too bloated for my projects, and the sticky header has to be a thead or the column sizes won't match up with the table's.

Comment: I don't see how else you're going to achieve this then