# Using translateY on thead and tbody messes up z-index

Tags: css, transform

I'm using transform: translateY on tbody and thead to position them in a large div.

```
table thead {
  transform: translateY(200px);
  background: green;
}

table tbody {
  transform: translateY(190px);
  background: blue;
}
```

In webkit (Chrome and Safari) the tbody overlays the thead - even when I add z-index to both selectors. [Here an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/YV2OsG2HR8wVQJ2HmgTb?p=preview). The thead should always be visible at all times, and the tbody should have a lower z-index being in the background.

Why is that is there a way around it?

Comment: Another answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816750/why-z-index-does-not-work-for-element-having-transform-translatey?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you specify `transform`, you create a new `stacking context`. Your z-index for `thead` and `tbody` no longer share a common context (which is why tbody is above thead, regardless of the specified z-index). Here's are a couple articles that discusses z-index and stacking context:

http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

The other article with a demo.

http://benfrain.com/z-index-stacking-contexts-experimental-css-and-ios-safari/

And a snippet from the spec itself:

> Any computed value other than none for the transform results in the creation of both a stacking context and a containing block. The object acts as a containing block for fixed positioned descendants.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-property

Unfortunately, you'll probably need to re-think your use of transform to work around the stacking context issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's interesting that Firefox is rendering it "correctly". I'm wondering how it implements the transform compared to webkit.

Comment: Good point, @bengro. According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-property) "Any computed value other than none for the transform results in the creation of both a stacking context and a containing block. The object acts as a containing block for fixed positioned descendants." If FireFox isn't creating a new stacking context, it would seem they're not following the spec.

Comment: Spent a long time searching for an explanation, and glad to have yours here. What do you mean by re-thinking the use of transform?

Comment: Thank you! The `other than none` helped me. I was setting `transform` with javascript, and I never needed the z-index and transform at the same time, so simply setting `transform` to `none` instead of `''` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 13):

I messed around a lot with `z-index` but didn't get anywhere.

So, working without `z-index`:

```
.table {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.thead {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
}

.tbody {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Note that `transform-style` has to be on parent.

It's a touch hacky but for lack of a better solution, here it is.

Comment: This worked! Wouldn't have thought to use translate3d

Comment: Absolute life saver. I had attempted translate3d already but did not know above the transform-style property.

Answer (score 3):

There is workaround to put thead after tbody in html,
browser will render it correctly, and thead will be positioned over tbody
since it's goes after.

```
<table>
    <tbody>...</tbody>
    <thead>...</thead>
</table>
```

This could also be done with javascript.

```
$('thead').appendTo('table');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, not setting transform on `tbody` would bring `thead` to the front. Then you could reposition the whole table by styling `table` rather than `thead`/`tbody`. Unfortunately, setting `transform` on either `thead` or `tbody` will not work in Internet Explorer. It will on `td`.

```
table {
    position: relative;
    top: 190px;
}

table thead {
    transform: translateY(10px);
    background: green;
}

table tbody {
    background: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c0485yjw/

See also: [-ms-transform won't work on table header group (thead) in IE10 (and below, presumably)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777485/ms-transform-wont-work-on-table-header-group-thead-in-ie10-and-below-presu/17884895#17884895)