# Why "z-index" does not work for element having transform: translateY()

Tags: html, css, transform

Below is the snippet:

```css
.up {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.down {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="up"></div>
<div class="down"></div>
```

As can be seen, the `.up` element has higher `z-index` than `.down` element. However, the `.down` element still locates in front of the `.up` element somehow..

Does anyone have ideas about this? How to fix this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. For `z-index` to work `position` must be applied as `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`. Add `position: relative;` to the `.down` element
2. As there is no parent-child hierarchy, negative `z-index` should be applied to make the element go behind.

**Demo**

```css
.up {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: .5; /* For DEMO Purpose */
  height: 100px;
  /* z-index: 100; /* Not required. Not work #1 */
}
.down {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: -1; /* Update this */
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: relative; /* Add this */
}
```

```html
<div class="up"></div>
<div class="down"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**[Note](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp):** z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

Add `position:relative` to `.up` class

```css
.up {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  opacity: .5;
}
.down {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="up"></div>
<div class="down"></div>
```

Comment: This is working because you've added `position` to the `.up` element also https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/1md7zggo/3/

Comment: Yes, this is also working, but totally depends on OP whether he can apply `position` to `.up` or `.down`

Comment: `z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)` so now you can remove the `z-index` of `.down`

Comment: Hehe yes, Thanks a lot for help me to improve my answer

Answer (score 1):

Just keep in mind that elements with non-static positioning will always appear on top of elements with default static positioning.

While you are dealing with two elements , you can use the values 0, 1 or -1. Dont complicate yourself with higher values.