# Freeze table header using HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with almost infinite rows andI need to make the table content scroll (tabebody), while keeping the header frozen (Keep header non scrollable)

I have the code That I am trying for,

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div align="center" id="id1" style="height: 240px;overflow:auto">
<table id="tbl" class="class1" align="center" width="100%" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="first"><input type="checkbox" id="select-all"></th>
            <th class="second">Edit</th>
            <th class="third">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="fourth">Timestamp</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td class="first"><input class="selects" type="checkbox" value="A1" id="r0"></td>
        <td class="second"><a target="_blank" href="www.uitshj.org?show=A1">1</a></td>
        <td class="third"><a href="#" class='option' id='option_1' >Option 1</a></td>
        <td class="fourth">2018-08-26T10:38:01.602Z</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="first"><input class="selects" type="checkbox" value="B1" id="r1"></td>
        <td class="second"><a target="_blank" href="www.uitshj.org?show=B1">2</a></td>
        <td class="third"><a href="#" class='option' id='option_2' >Option 2</a></td>
        <td class="fourth">2018-08-26T10:23:42.119Z</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="first"><input class="selects" type="checkbox" value="C1" id="r2"></td>
        <td class="second"><a target="_blank" href="www.uitshj.org?show=C1">3</a></td>
        <td class="third"><a href="#" class='option' id='option_3'>Option 3</a></td>
        <td class="fourth">2018-08-26T01:05:00.171Z</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<script>

var myJson = {
  option_1: {'name': 'Clark', age:'39', address:'Washington D.C.'},
  option_2: {'name': 'Bob', age:'26', address:'Texas'},
  option_3: {'name': 'Angelina', age:'31', address:'Ohio'}
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.option').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    values = myJson[id];

    parent = $(this).parent('td')
    existing_content = parent.find('.option_content')
    if( existing_content.length ){ //if content exists, remove it
      existing_content.remove()
    } else { //else add the content
      content = "<div class='option_content'>" + values.name + "<br>" + values.age + "<br>" + values.address + "</div>";
      $(this).after(content)
    }
  })
})
</script>
```

How do I keep the table header to be non scrollable?

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723996/htmlcss-table-with-fixed-thead-and-scrollable-tbody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.. in other words, assuming you've got the width of all cells worked out by your classes (first, second, third, fourth). All you need to do is to add these two lines of code to your styles section:

```
<style type='text/css'>
  .class1 > thead { display: table; }
  .class1 > tbody { display: block; overflow: scroll; height: 240px; }
</style>
```

And it should work.