# Fix rows in html table exported from excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've below html code of table exported from excel macro. Now I want to fix its headers while scrolling as there will be many rows in a table. Any way to do this.

I tried with `position:fixed` for rows but it just mess-up table layout.

Any help please.

https://jsfiddle.net/samadhan10/8ya5rg7k/

I tried solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723996/table-with-fixed-thead-and-scrollable-tbody) but the cell alignment is messed-up.

https://jsfiddle.net/samadhan10/ogavsejm/1/

Comment: You need to use a jQuery Plugin which fixes Table Header. There are many available.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by exporting data and header rows separately in html pages. Then modified the file having header and added them in a fixed div:

```
<div  position="fixed">
...
</div>
```

Embedded data file using `iframe`:

```
<div>
   <iframe src="data.html" marginwidth="60" width="1244" height="1500" align="center"> 
   </iframe>
</div>
```