# Horizontally and vertically scrollable large table

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, scroll

Well, here you are a next post about the boring scrolling table with fixed header and footer. This topic is comes from rigid structure of HTML. The source problem was to show really huge table overflowing the screen width as the height. My wish was also to fix the header at the top of the table and so its copy at the bottom of it.

After an intensive googling and testing lot of guaranteed codes I found next deep-nested problems:
- the header and footer do not keep the cell-spacing of table body while tbody is separately scrolled
- the tbody rows overwrite the header 
- the vertical scrolling of tbody can be hardly combined with horizontal scrolling of the whole table (including header and footer).

I started to write some kind of hack to overcome it but it depends on used browser, too.

```html
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>pokus</title><script>var tab=
[{"id":"1","uuid":"b25202a1-c732-f5e4-c976-f725092a9f02","count":"19622","hash":"fddf1277943af21b9282bd6a4ff53bc19168854e","diff":"151621","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:26","speed":"29553600"}
,{"id":"2","uuid":"ade0f2a7-6838-d1f3-646c-7c238a9383a9","count":"24794","hash":"2b52c53b1775c7729d873db22d23adc38d13c99f","diff":"151622","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"29685192"}
,{"id":"3","uuid":"1040a7f3-aee2-69cd-7be8-97683c1dd406","count":"64495","hash":"585421d85d3bc6f068cb1b0da2a3587f585bdd9e","diff":"151623","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:24","speed":"51766808"}
,{"id":"4","uuid":"f2bc0ef7-bc05-d425-1b73-451ba5b08011","count":"71693","hash":"150c32da8771141b1d3ed4725389ee3496d6218f","diff":"151624","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:24","speed":"53923592"}
,{"id":"5","uuid":"763153c1-ce21-db34-f98a-703457575ce0","count":"92657","hash":"db82a3cfc601db58d0a41f9928e371dfe40067fa","diff":"151625","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:24","speed":"29923912"}
,{"id":"6","uuid":"ddf160de-a052-7404-cfcc-36605c5a01ce","count":"57471","hash":"8edc173bb8e9cc89f0525e59bfa17c486aefd9d9","diff":"151626","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:24","speed":"53787840"}
,{"id":"7","uuid":"3aa65601-7834-a62e-fe5d-fbd0b4e703c7","count":"79016","hash":"0f8c4ce07af5730c60550d64e3160950bd1994e0","diff":"151627","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:24","speed":"20422664"}
,{"id":"8","uuid":"16bee402-b87d-8172-daf3-f918b0d9f2ff","count":"8929","hash":"ec563d631f981a5770dea4bf7390b79eb3e649ce","diff":"151628","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"43552496"}
,{"id":"9","uuid":"3b1b3e69-0ad0-4c9c-f786-ca6fc30c6f65","count":"9863","hash":"89c20f5552fb74461c67ba9a3bc13ec8b66bf6b3","diff":"151531","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"272836232"}
,{"id":"10","uuid":"b64d86b0-fcab-2120-18cc-a6efaabbafe0","count":"2893","hash":"e0fb5a4dad9f7804e8d7c51f3f1c49f17e21e45a","diff":"151658","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"35025144"}
,{"id":"11","uuid":"df8dd8bd-c9df-a8fc-977e-0f89c6a2e017","count":"9952","hash":"1f89b65e230f0525ea41b27b7e3548daedb5b1a8","diff":"151532","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"274418184"}
,{"id":"12","uuid":"53f39083-5999-dddf-30e2-4b53d1bf3fa4","count":"346","hash":"eb7f5723b9ed7239ecbf951ea51b3c8927c29b72","diff":"151659","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"0"}
,{"id":"13","uuid":"af2bde11-bce2-f032-877b-129e7bc866a3","count":"61041","hash":"a513d5bec7fe514ec76083d299b8d71a9c7781fb","diff":"151660","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:24","speed":"35088848"}
,{"id":"14","uuid":"e43a1bb1-d369-8f21-0f10-306c3c259952","count":"48343","hash":"8d8c0fa097c7f52b766b17c09ca14475add4753a","diff":"151661","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:32","speed":"35113504"}
,{"id":"15","uuid":"660f22da-06fd-3794-6876-5f90718ea73c","count":"25185","hash":"27057106809aafcc4cfe3d2b93d394f07c0d06d1", "diff":"151662","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:32","speed":"8068040"}
,{"id":"16","uuid":"8bd5be38-7a78-aed8-d123-fabf2eb56d7c","count":"2873","hash":"d95f01753799d34551e434343e4fcb04d0df1151","diff":"151631","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"80558744"}
,{"id":"17","uuid":"dbbb3ca5-5fcc-844c-20e8-fd38ef74dbde","count":"48255","hash":"193a3132b41ccfefde9b91dadb196ae184ab5fb3","diff":"151663","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:24","speed":"35001152"}
,{"id":"18","uuid":"73807ab9-b253-d804-5ea6-8d702a81ca51","count":"14286","hash":"f797c0a6f201db68df69136085954758e0b637c7","diff":"151674","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"43866360"}
,{"id":"19","uuid":"8c5aaf9e-11e4-08d5-76ad-8c65ea62faf2","count":"80511","hash":"81bae19474f4ebb309765c9cb1147269117b4538", "diff":"151669","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:24","speed":"62409648"}
,{"id":"20","uuid":"bbc42163-ffab-66b2-58dc-3d310c9a69bd","count":"26971","hash":"05d09c340ee28bbfc0f6ebc00620220b87be0f78","diff":"151670","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:24","speed":"35116608"}
,{"id":"21","uuid":"46c0f5e8-90ee-1b0b-38bd-958cda7469f5","count":"83311","hash":"8af8ca1f5912a157cca0d333c38e439b036f671d", "diff":"151671","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:24","speed":"34999840"}
,{"id":"22","uuid":"8df0d389-a377-b96b-f52d-b9c80bb67050","count":"30633","hash":"d13ebcc7579cee7f94ed75e11105fa2a88dcc5d0","diff":"151672","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:24","speed":"21122312"}
,{"id":"23","uuid":"03c68084-9fe9-0f72-41d1-39a0cb3cb779","count":"33989","hash":"2b15ae3e8a60e88a9f4ddff0c4599fe9d75b1e86","diff":"151673","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:32","speed":"32835424"}
,{"id":"24","uuid":"5713d483-55a1-14a0-3ffa-11e3266ca036","count":"7848","hash":"12fb05be8bfbecdd63c308a2e90c187e2e42ace7","diff":"151675","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"41465896"}
,{"id":"25","uuid":"a25bb497-4172-cb53-2fed-12139fc2de9f","count":"359","hash":"14d5c1105b0f5e24bbf28c8a519b3f5d0606d97a","diff":"151676","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"0"}
,{"id":"26","uuid":"ca38be26-78f7-5e7f-b1cd-51fcfcb9c711","count":"418","hash":"0e72c5d8e3156c6832c0d1acdc2e27dbd1fb0faa","diff":"151677","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"0"}
,{"id":"27","uuid":"4f51aad3-5c1d-b52d-2a65-fa95d2b8c5c8","count":"393","hash":"a01b90a813230b5faeaf6010d847be1ab65cf9b7","diff":"151684","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"0"}
,{"id":"28","uuid":"bfa8b76e-c159-1d20-475c-33d617480e88","count":"373","hash":"72cacce09e5ae1c9f7d5c0d9bbbf8dd1e21ed11f","diff":"151685","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"0"}
,{"id":"29","uuid":"f7014ffd-e5b3-3854-cf34-e8cec902c684","count":"156604","hash":"d12efcfc16f83d347a9a04d7547aa947a02dff9c","diff":"151686","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:32","speed":"35023128"}
,{"id":"30","uuid":"6bda4364-6952-12f1-3e11-2687c501a08a","count":"1024","hash":"4776e8f8df67537a4bc357ae5407486befa36eea","diff":"151687","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"43956480"}
]; var _tr_ =document.createElement('tr');var _td_ =document.createElement('td');
function fill_table() 
{ var thd=document.getElementById('hot'); var tbd=document.getElementById('bot'); 
  var poc=tab.length;var hada=thd.firstChild.firstChild;var dada=tbd.firstChild.firstChild; 
  for(var klic in tab[0]){ var hela=document.createElement("th"); hela.innerHTML=klic; hada.appendChild(hela);}; 
  for(var i=0;i< poc;i++)  // after header assembled the table rows are cloned and filled
  { var ntr=_tr_.cloneNode(false);  // clone free row
    for( klic in tab[i])            // with each table row clone free cell and fill it 
    { var ntd=_td_.cloneNode(false); ntd.innerHTML=tab[i][klic];  ntr.appendChild(ntd); 
    } tbd.firstElementChild.appendChild(ntr); // show next row 
  } var lol=tbd.rows[0].cells.length; var maxirka=0;
  for (var k=0;k < lol;k++){ maxirka += thd.rows[0].cells[k].style.width=tbd.rows[0].cells[k].offsetWidth;}; 
  thd.style.width=maxirka;
  var tfd=document.getElementById('iak').appendChild(thd.cloneNode(true));tfd.id='fot';
  var tfh=tfd.offsetHeight; var tih=document.getElementById('iak').offsetHeight;
  tbd.style.height=tih-tfh-tfh-15;tbd.firstElementChild.style.height=tih-tfh-tfh-20;
}
</script></head><body onLoad="fill_table()"><br>
<div id="iak" style="overflow:scroll;overflow-y:hidden; width:60%;  height:60%;border:#888888 1px solid; " >
  <table id="hot" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout:fixed;border-collapse:collapse;"><thead><tr></tr></thead></table>
  <table id="bot" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; height:200px; white-space: nowrap;">
    <tbody style="display:block; width:100%; height:200px; overflow:scroll; overflow-x:hidden;"></tbody></table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The solution is based on creating three tables: header-table, data-table, footer-table (clone of the header-table) , enclosed in horizontally scrolled DIV. 
After the  header-table and data-table are built, the auto-generated cell-with of the data-table is copied to the corresponding cell of header-table. 
Some disadvantage is that the vertical scroll-bar is hidden on the right side of the table, but you can vertically scroll with mouse-wheel or show the bar by horizontal scroll into full right.
May here someone shows some better solution based on CSS, what will be really fine, but it could be better if W3C group were add the normal scrolling behavior of the  definition into the next HTML version.

Hm, this post was written as a functional sample of html scrollable table with fixed header and footer always visible. Not less, nor more, neither the nice decoration. And the basic task was to write it as easy as it possible. As this table is intented to be a part of more complex html page, with formulas and other tables, hence globals CSS are excluded. After a heavy development of HTML features in last 30 years by W3C, I ecpected something like:

```html
<table style="overflow:scroll; overflow-y:hidden; display:@in_parent_element_only">

  <thead style="'header cells corresponding with table cells'">
         <row><!--single row header  --></row></thead>
  <tbody style="overflow:scroll; overflow-x:hidden; 'full_view_table'">
         <row><!--lot of rows    --></row></tbody>
  <tfoot ><row><!--copy of header --></row></tfoot>

</table>
```

Unfortunately, this is supposed to bee a too much simple way - realy I tested lot of style combinations but either the THEAD and TBODY cells are not related (why?), or the THEAD, TBODY, TFOOT rows ovelaps or displace each other and vice versa.

I know, that a very nice result can be hunt by heavy computing, positioning, and styling, but I insist on simplicity and functionality, preferring information over ornaments.

If somebody knows what combination of inline `style=".."` can guarantee the good result regardless on browser type, please try to write here a piece of well commented code. Not only for me, but for the comunity, just as I showed here my primitive way.

Answer (score 2):

I've got edgy in my research of this old code,  so I made a new one ;-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Scrolling Table - Mister Jojo</title>
  <style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color:lightsteelblue
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: 0;
}
table { margin:0; border-collapse: collapse }

table tbody td { 
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: .2em .5em; 
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
}
table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {background:lightcyan }  
table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {background:white } 

#Table-Boxes {
  display          : block;
  position     : relative;
  margin       : 1em;
  --top_fix    : 30px;
  --left_fix   : 40px;
  --scroll_bar : 16px;
  width        : 600px; 
  height       : 400px;
  resize       : both;
  overflow     : hidden;
  background-color:ghostwhite;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 70px;
}
#Table-Boxes > div > span {
  text-align: center;
  padding   : .4em .5em; 
  border    : 1px solid cadetblue;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  display: inline-block;
}
#Table-Boxes > div {
  display : block;
  position: absolute;
  margin  : 0
}
#Label-top-left {
  top     : 0;
  left    : 0; 
}
#Labels-OnTop {
  top     : 0;
  left    : var(--left_fix);
  width     : calc(100% - var(--left_fix) - var(--scroll_bar) ); 
  height  : var(--top_fix);
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#Labels-OnLeft {
  top     : var(--top_fix);
  left    : 0;
  width     : var(--left_fix);
  height    : calc(100% - var(--top_fix)  - var(--scroll_bar) ); 
  overflow: hidden;
}
#Table-Content {
  top     : var(--top_fix);
  left    : var(--left_fix);
  height    : calc(100% - var(--top_fix)  - var(--scroll_bar) ); 
  width     : calc(100% - var(--left_fix) - var(--scroll_bar) ); 
  overflow: hidden;
}
#Bar-V { 
  top  : var(--top_fix);
  right: 0;
  width: var(--scroll_bar);
  height: calc(100% - var(--top_fix)  - var(--scroll_bar) ); 
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#Bar-H { 
  left  : var(--left_fix);
  bottom: 0;
  height: var(--scroll_bar);
  width: calc(100% - var(--left_fix) - var(--scroll_bar) ); 
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="Table-Boxes">
    <div id="Label-top-left"></div>
    <div id="Labels-OnTop"></div>
    <div id="Labels-OnLeft">
      <table><tbody></tbody></table>
    </div>
    <div id="Table-Content">
      <table><tbody></tbody></table>
    </div>
    <div id="Bar-V"><span>&thinsp;</span></div>
    <div id="Bar-H"><span>&thinsp;</span></div>
  </div>

<script>
  var Data_tab = 
    [ { "id"       : "1"
      , "uuid"     : "b25202a1-c732-f5e4-c976-f725092a9f02"
      , "count"    : "19622"
      , "hash"     : "fddf1277943af21b9282bd6a4ff53bc19168854e"
      , "diff"     : "151621"
      , "timestamp": "2017-08-23 14:31:26"
      , "speed"    : "29553600"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "2"
      , "uuid"     : "ade0f2a7-6838-d1f3-646c-7c238a9383a9"
      , "count"    : "24794"
      , "hash"     : "2b52c53b1775c7729d873db22d23adc38d13c99f"
      , "diff"     : "151622"
      , "timestamp": "2017-05-25 14:12:34"
      , "speed"    : "29685192"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "3"
      , "uuid"     : "1040a7f3-aee2-69cd-7be8-97683c1dd406"
      , "count"    : "64495"
      , "hash"     : "585421d85d3bc6f068cb1b0da2a3587f585bdd9e"
      , "diff"     : "151623"
      , "timestamp": "2017-08-23 14:31:24"
      , "speed"    : "51766808"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "4"
      , "uuid"     : "f2bc0ef7-bc05-d425-1b73-451ba5b08011"
      , "count"    : "71693"
      , "hash"     : "150c32da8771141b1d3ed4725389ee3496d6218f"
      , "diff"     : "151624"
      , "timestamp": "2017-08-23 14:31:24"
      , "speed"    : "53923592"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "5"
      , "uuid"     : "763153c1-ce21-db34-f98a-703457575ce0"
      , "count"    : "92657"
      , "hash"     : "db82a3cfc601db58d0a41f9928e371dfe40067fa"
      , "diff"     : "151625"
      , "timestamp": "2017-08-23 14:31:24"
      , "speed"    : "29923912"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "6"
      , "uuid"     : "ddf160de-a052-7404-cfcc-36605c5a01ce"
      , "count"    : "57471"
      , "hash"     : "8edc173bb8e9cc89f0525e59bfa17c486aefd9d9"
      , "diff"     : "151626"
      , "timestamp": "2017-08-23 14:31:24"
      , "speed"    : "53787840"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "7"
      , "uuid"     : "3aa65601-7834-a62e-fe5d-fbd0b4e703c7"
      , "count"    : "79016"
      , "hash"     : "0f8c4ce07af5730c60550d64e3160950bd1994e0"
      , "diff"     : "151627"
      , "timestamp": "2017-08-23 14:31:24"
      , "speed"    : "20422664"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "8"
      , "uuid"     : "16bee402-b87d-8172-daf3-f918b0d9f2ff"
      , "count"    : "8929"
      , "hash"     : "ec563d631f981a5770dea4bf7390b79eb3e649ce"
      , "diff"     : "151628"
      , "timestamp": "2017-05-25 14:12:34"
      , "speed"    : "43552496"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "9"
      , "uuid"     : "3b1b3e69-0ad0-4c9c-f786-ca6fc30c6f65"
      , "count"    : "9863"
      , "hash"     : "89c20f5552fb74461c67ba9a3bc13ec8b66bf6b3"
      , "diff"     : "151531"
      , "timestamp": "2017-05-25 14:12:34"
      , "speed"    : "272836232"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "10"
      , "uuid"     : "b64d86b0-fcab-2120-18cc-a6efaabbafe0"
      , "count"    : "2893"
      , "hash"     : "e0fb5a4dad9f7804e8d7c51f3f1c49f17e21e45a"
      , "diff"     : "151658"
      , "timestamp": "2017-05-25 14:12:34"
      , "speed"    : "35025144"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "11"
      , "uuid"     : "df8dd8bd-c9df-a8fc-977e-0f89c6a2e017"
      , "count"    : "9952"
      , "hash"     : "1f89b65e230f0525ea41b27b7e3548daedb5b1a8"
      , "diff"     : "151532"
      , "timestamp": "2017-05-25 14:12:34"
      , "speed"    : "274418184"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "12"
      , "uuid"     : "53f39083-5999-dddf-30e2-4b53d1bf3fa4"
      , "count"    : "346"
      , "hash"     : "eb7f5723b9ed7239ecbf951ea51b3c8927c29b72"
      , "diff"     : "151659"
      , "timestamp": "2017-05-25 14:12:34"
      , "speed"    : "0"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "13"
      , "uuid"     : "af2bde11-bce2-f032-877b-129e7bc866a3"
      , "count"    : "61041"
      , "hash"     : "a513d5bec7fe514ec76083d299b8d71a9c7781fb"
      , "diff"     : "151660"
      , "timestamp": "2017-08-23 14:31:24"
      , "speed"    : "35088848"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "14"
      , "uuid"     : "e43a1bb1-d369-8f21-0f10-306c3c259952"
      , "count"    : "48343"
      , "hash"     : "8d8c0fa097c7f52b766b17c09ca14475add4753a"
      , "diff"     : "151661"
      , "timestamp": "2017-05-25 14:12:32"
      , "speed"    : "35113504"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "15"
      , "uuid"     : "660f22da-06fd-3794-6876-5f90718ea73c"
      , "count"    : "25185"
      , "hash"     : "27057106809aafcc4cfe3d2b93d394f07c0d06d1"
      , "diff"     : "151662"
      , "timestamp": "2017-05-25 14:12:32"
      , "speed"    : "8068040"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "16"
      , "uuid"     : "8bd5be38-7a78-aed8-d123-fabf2eb56d7c"
      , "count"    : "2873"
      , "hash"     : "d95f01753799d34551e434343e4fcb04d0df1151"
      , "diff"     : "151631"
      , "timestamp": "2017-05-25 14:12:34"
      , "speed"    : "80558744"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "17"
      , "uuid"     : "dbbb3ca5-5fcc-844c-20e8-fd38ef74dbde"
      , "count"    : "48255"
      , "hash"     : "193a3132b41ccfefde9b91dadb196ae184ab5fb3"
      , "diff"     : "151663"
      , "timestamp": "2017-08-23 14:31:24"
      , "speed"    : "35001152"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "18"
      , "uuid"     : "73807ab9-b253-d804-5ea6-8d702a81ca51"
      , "count"    : "14286"
      , "hash"     : "f797c0a6f201db68df69136085954758e0b637c7"
      , "diff"     : "151674"
      , "timestamp": "2017-05-25 14:12:34"
      , "speed"    : "43866360"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "19"
      , "uuid"     : "8c5aaf9e-11e4-08d5-76ad-8c65ea62faf2"
      , "count"    : "80511"
      , "hash"     : "81bae19474f4ebb309765c9cb1147269117b4538"
      , "diff"     : "151669"
      , "timestamp": "2017-08-23 14:31:24"
      , "speed"    : "62409648"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "20"
      , "uuid"     : "bbc42163-ffab-66b2-58dc-3d310c9a69bd"
      , "count"    : "26971"
      , "hash"     : "05d09c340ee28bbfc0f6ebc00620220b87be0f78"
      , "diff"     : "151670"
      , "timestamp": "2017-08-23 14:31:24"
      , "speed"    : "35116608"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "21"
      , "uuid"     : "46c0f5e8-90ee-1b0b-38bd-958cda7469f5"
      , "count"    : "83311"
      , "hash"     : "8af8ca1f5912a157cca0d333c38e439b036f671d"
      , "diff"     : "151671"
      , "timestamp": "2017-08-23 14:31:24"
      , "speed"    : "34999840"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "22"
      , "uuid"     : "8df0d389-a377-b96b-f52d-b9c80bb67050"
      , "count"    : "30633"
      , "hash"     : "d13ebcc7579cee7f94ed75e11105fa2a88dcc5d0"
      , "diff"     : "151672"
      , "timestamp": "2017-08-23 14:31:24"
      , "speed"    : "21122312"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "23"
      , "uuid"     : "03c68084-9fe9-0f72-41d1-39a0cb3cb779"
      , "count"    : "33989"
      , "hash"     : "2b15ae3e8a60e88a9f4ddff0c4599fe9d75b1e86"
      , "diff"     : "151673"
      , "timestamp": "2017-05-25 14:12:32"
      , "speed"    : "32835424"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "24"
      , "uuid"     : "5713d483-55a1-14a0-3ffa-11e3266ca036"
      , "count"    : "7848"
      , "hash"     : "12fb05be8bfbecdd63c308a2e90c187e2e42ace7"
      , "diff"     : "151675"
      , "timestamp": "2017-05-25 14:12:34"
      , "speed"    : "41465896"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "25"      , "uuid": "a25bb497-4172-cb53-2fed-12139fc2de9f"
      , "count"    : "359"
      , "hash"     : "14d5c1105b0f5e24bbf28c8a519b3f5d0606d97a"
      , "diff"     : "151676"
      , "timestamp": "2017-05-25 14:12:34"
      , "speed"    : "0"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "26"
      , "uuid"     : "ca38be26-78f7-5e7f-b1cd-51fcfcb9c711"
      , "count"    : "418"
      , "hash"     : "0e72c5d8e3156c6832c0d1acdc2e27dbd1fb0faa"
      , "diff"     : "151677"
      , "timestamp": "2017-05-25 14:12:34"
      , "speed"    : "0"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "27"
      , "uuid"     : "4f51aad3-5c1d-b52d-2a65-fa95d2b8c5c8"
      , "count"    : "393"
      , "hash"     : "a01b90a813230b5faeaf6010d847be1ab65cf9b7"
      , "diff"     : "151684"
      , "timestamp": "2017-05-25 14:12:34"
      , "speed"    : "0"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "28"
      , "uuid"     : "bfa8b76e-c159-1d20-475c-33d617480e88"
      , "count"    : "373"
      , "hash"     : "72cacce09e5ae1c9f7d5c0d9bbbf8dd1e21ed11f"
      , "diff"     : "151685"
      , "timestamp": "2017-05-25 14:12:34"
      , "speed"    : "0"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "29"
      , "uuid"     : "f7014ffd-e5b3-3854-cf34-e8cec902c684"
      , "count"    : "156604"
      , "hash"     : "d12efcfc16f83d347a9a04d7547aa947a02dff9c"
      , "diff"     : "151686"
      , "timestamp": "2017-05-25 14:12:32"
      , "speed"    : "35023128"
      } 
    , { "id"       : "30"
      , "uuid"     : "6bda4364-6952-12f1-3e11-2687c501a08a"
      , "count"    : "1024"
      , "hash"     : "4776e8f8df67537a4bc357ae5407486befa36eea"
      , "diff"     : "151687"
      , "timestamp": "2017-05-25 14:12:34"
      , "speed"    : "43956480"
      } 
    ] 

const TableBoxes   = document.querySelector('#Table-Boxes')
    , Head_Table   = document.querySelector('#Labels-OnTop')
    , Label_tl     = document.querySelector('#Label-top-left')
    , Cols_Table   = document.querySelector('#Labels-OnLeft table tbody')
    , moving_Table = document.querySelector('#Table-Content table tbody')
    , LabelsOnLeft = document.querySelector('#Labels-OnLeft')
    , TableContent = document.querySelector('#Table-Content')
    , Scroll_V     = document.querySelector('#Bar-V')
    , Scroll_H     = document.querySelector('#Bar-H')
    , Tspan        = document.createElement('span')

TableBoxes.style.setProperty('--scroll_bar', getScrollbarWidth()+'px')

// set Head table columns names
C_Names = Object.entries(Data_tab[0]).map(e=>e[0])  // get names

// fill tables..
for(let r_tab of Data_tab)
{
  let fixRow = Cols_Table.insertRow(-1)
  let movRow = moving_Table.insertRow(-1)
  C_Names.forEach((c_tab,i)=>{
    if (i===0) fixRow.insertCell(0).textContent     = r_tab[c_tab]    
    else       movRow.insertCell((i-1)).textContent = r_tab[c_tab]
  })
}

// top left label
let xLabel         = Tspan.cloneNode()
xLabel.textContent = C_Names[0]
xLabel.style.width = Cols_Table.rows[0].cells[0].offsetWidth +'px';
Label_tl.appendChild(xLabel) 

// harmoniz sizes...
TableBoxes.style.setProperty('--top_fix', (xLabel.offsetHeight +1) +'px')
TableBoxes.style.setProperty('--left_fix', (Cols_Table.rows[0].cells[0].offsetWidth +1) +'px')

Scroll_H.querySelector('span').style.width  = moving_Table.offsetWidth +'px';
Scroll_V.querySelector('span').style.height = moving_Table.offsetHeight +'px';

C_Names.forEach( (hTab,i)=>{
  if(i>0) {
    let xLabel         = Tspan.cloneNode()
    xLabel.textContent = hTab
    xLabel.style.width = moving_Table.rows[0].cells[(i-1)].offsetWidth +'px'
    Head_Table.appendChild(xLabel) 
  }
})

// scrolls synchros...
Scroll_V.scrollTop  = 0
Scroll_H.scrollLeft = 0

Scroll_V.onscroll=e=>{
  LabelsOnLeft.scrollTop = Scroll_V.scrollTop
  TableContent.scrollTop = Scroll_V.scrollTop
}
Scroll_H.onscroll=e=>{
  Head_Table.scrollLeft   = Scroll_H.scrollLeft
  TableContent.scrollLeft = Scroll_H.scrollLeft
}

//  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382516/getting-scroll-bar-width-using-javascript  Nov 2014
function getScrollbarWidth()
{
  // Creating invisible container
  const outer                 = document.createElement('div')
  outer.style.visibility      = 'hidden'
  outer.style.overflow        = 'scroll'    // forcing scrollbar to appear
  outer.style.msOverflowStyle = 'scrollbar' // needed for WinJS apps
  document.body.appendChild(outer)

  // Creating inner element and placing it in the container
  const inner = document.createElement('div')
  outer.appendChild(inner)

  // Calculating difference between container's full width and the child width
  const scrollbarWidth = (outer.offsetWidth - inner.offsetWidth)

  // Removing temporary elements from the DOM
  outer.parentNode.removeChild(outer)

  return scrollbarWidth
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks nice, thanks, but the complaint remains: it should had to be included in the html attributes (after 30 html years)

Comment: My sigh does not touch you, Mister Jojo, you got my tanks. I did not want to wound you. If there were some open forum for the real improvement HTML I would like to see it to know what they deal with. Formerly the main goal of HTML was to bring a mostly text information fully customisable in graphic way by reader. The PDF on the other hand was format for keeping the graphics regardless of the reader's habits. I am disgusted about the current trend of development. I am sorry for spreading my bad mood.

Comment: Please, look at the last edited appendix of the question

Answer (score 1):

I made a deep search in stackoverflow answer to similar questions, and rewrite my solution with a portion of CSS (even not fully understood).

Data are generated with PHP request to psql database, hence it can return really large table which scrolling is necessary.

The CSS section is compiled from various sources carefully consulted with CSS tutorials and handbooks. But the main inspiration came from "http://stackoverflow.com/users/9557859" answer of "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723996" question (both on this site).

Well, let us show the sample:

```js
var tab=
[{"id":"1","uuid":"b25202a1-c732-f5e4-c976-f725092a9f02","count":"19622","hash":"fddf1277943af21b9282bd6a4ff53bc19168854e","diff":"151621","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:26","speed":"29553600"}
,{"id":"2","uuid":"ade0f2a7-6838-d1f3-646c-7c238a9383a9","count":"24794","hash":"2b52c53b1775c7729d873db22d23adc38d13c99f","diff":"151622","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"29685192"}
,{"id":"3","uuid":"1040a7f3-aee2-69cd-7be8-97683c1dd406","count":"64495","hash":"585421d85d3bc6f068cb1b0da2a3587f585bdd9e","diff":"151623","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:24","speed":"51766808"}
,{"id":"4","uuid":"f2bc0ef7-bc05-d425-1b73-451ba5b08011","count":"71693","hash":"150c32da8771141b1d3ed4725389ee3496d6218f","diff":"151624","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:24","speed":"53923592"}
,{"id":"5","uuid":"763153c1-ce21-db34-f98a-703457575ce0","count":"92657","hash":"db82a3cfc601db58d0a41f9928e371dfe40067fa","diff":"151625","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:24","speed":"29923912"}
,{"id":"6","uuid":"ddf160de-a052-7404-cfcc-36605c5a01ce","count":"57471","hash":"8edc173bb8e9cc89f0525e59bfa17c486aefd9d9","diff":"151626","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:24","speed":"53787840"}
,{"id":"7","uuid":"3aa65601-7834-a62e-fe5d-fbd0b4e703c7","count":"79016","hash":"0f8c4ce07af5730c60550d64e3160950bd1994e0","diff":"151627","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:24","speed":"20422664"}
,{"id":"8","uuid":"16bee402-b87d-8172-daf3-f918b0d9f2ff","count":"8929","hash":"ec563d631f981a5770dea4bf7390b79eb3e649ce","diff":"151628","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"43552496"}
,{"id":"9","uuid":"3b1b3e69-0ad0-4c9c-f786-ca6fc30c6f65","count":"9863","hash":"89c20f5552fb74461c67ba9a3bc13ec8b66bf6b3","diff":"151531","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"272836232"}
,{"id":"10","uuid":"b64d86b0-fcab-2120-18cc-a6efaabbafe0","count":"2893","hash":"e0fb5a4dad9f7804e8d7c51f3f1c49f17e21e45a","diff":"151658","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"35025144"}
,{"id":"11","uuid":"df8dd8bd-c9df-a8fc-977e-0f89c6a2e017","count":"9952","hash":"1f89b65e230f0525ea41b27b7e3548daedb5b1a8","diff":"151532","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"274418184"}
,{"id":"12","uuid":"53f39083-5999-dddf-30e2-4b53d1bf3fa4","count":"346","hash":"eb7f5723b9ed7239ecbf951ea51b3c8927c29b72","diff":"151659","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"0"}
,{"id":"13","uuid":"af2bde11-bce2-f032-877b-129e7bc866a3","count":"61041","hash":"a513d5bec7fe514ec76083d299b8d71a9c7781fb","diff":"151660","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:24","speed":"35088848"}
,{"id":"14","uuid":"e43a1bb1-d369-8f21-0f10-306c3c259952","count":"48343","hash":"8d8c0fa097c7f52b766b17c09ca14475add4753a","diff":"151661","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:32","speed":"35113504"}
,{"id":"15","uuid":"660f22da-06fd-3794-6876-5f90718ea73c","count":"25185","hash":"27057106809aafcc4cfe3d2b93d394f07c0d06d1", "diff":"151662","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:32","speed":"8068040"}
,{"id":"16","uuid":"8bd5be38-7a78-aed8-d123-fabf2eb56d7c","count":"2873","hash":"d95f01753799d34551e434343e4fcb04d0df1151","diff":"151631","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"80558744"}
,{"id":"17","uuid":"dbbb3ca5-5fcc-844c-20e8-fd38ef74dbde","count":"48255","hash":"193a3132b41ccfefde9b91dadb196ae184ab5fb3","diff":"151663","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:24","speed":"35001152"}
,{"id":"18","uuid":"73807ab9-b253-d804-5ea6-8d702a81ca51","count":"14286","hash":"f797c0a6f201db68df69136085954758e0b637c7","diff":"151674","timestamp":"2017-05-25 14:12:34","speed":"43866360"}
,{"id":"19","uuid":"8c5aaf9e-11e4-08d5-76ad-8c65ea62faf2","count":"80511","hash":"81bae19474f4ebb309765c9cb1147269117b4538", "diff":"151669","timestamp":"2017-08-23 14:31:24","speed":"62409648"}
]; var _tr_ =document.createElement('tr');var _td_ =document.createElement('td');var _th_ =document.createElement('th');var poc=tab.length;
function fill_table() 
{ var tbt=document.getElementById('bt'); var tbh=tbt.getElementsByTagName('thead')[0]; var tbb=tbt.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]; var tbf=tbt.getElementsByTagName('tfoot')[0]; 
  var ntr=_tr_.cloneNode(false);for(var klic in tab[0]){var nth=_th_.cloneNode(false);nth.innerHTML=klic;        ntr.appendChild(nth);};tbh.appendChild(ntr);
  for(var i=0;i< poc;i++)
  { var ntr=_tr_.cloneNode(false);for( klic in tab[i] ){var ntd=_td_.cloneNode(false);ntd.innerHTML=tab[i][klic];ntr.appendChild(ntd);};tbb.appendChild(ntr);  
  } tbf.appendChild(tbh.rows[0].cloneNode(true));for(i=0;i<tbb.rows.length;i++){ tbb.rows[i].cells[0].className="coll-sticky";}
}
```

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;white-space: nowrap;}
.coll-sticky {background: aquamarine;position: sticky;left: 0px;}
.tabl-sticky>tfoot>tr>th {background: aquamarine;position: sticky;bottom: 0px;}
.tabl-sticky>thead>tr>th {background: aquamarine;position: sticky;top: 0px;}
.tabl-height {height: 320px;display: block;overflow: scroll;width: 100%;}
.tabl-bordered>thead>tr>th,
.tabl-bordered>tfoot>tr>th,
.tabl-bordered>tbody>tr>td {border: 1px solid black;}
.tabl-zebra>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd) {background: lightgray }
```

```html
<body onLoad="fill_table()"><br>
<table border="1" >
  <tr style="height:100px;">
    <td style="width:100px;" align="center" >LOGO</td>
    <td style="width:600px; background:azure;" align="center" >filter</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="max-height:400px;">
    <td style="width:100px; background:azure;"  align="center" >Left<br>menu</td>
    <td style="width:600px; display: block;">
     <div class=" tabl-height">
      <table id="bt" class="tabl-bordered tabl-sticky tabl-zebra">
        <thead></thead><tbody></tbody><tfoot></tfoot>
      </table>
     </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table></body>
```

The solution is embeded into an example of a page built for a control and filter the database extraction.

The data table is nested in a `<DIV>` element and the header/footer row and first column are sticked to the top and left DIV edge respectively. The use of parent `<DIV>` prevent the problems with disorder of columns of `<THEAD> - <TBODY>` columns.

Please note, the elements have to be sticked are `<TH> / <TD>` and their background color has to be set even to "white" colour, because if you let it the default color "none" their text is dirty with text scrolled over.

This looks for me yet as simple as is possible, it gives an understandable and usable result, and you can decorate it as you wish.

This table was tested in Chrome, and particulary in Firefox. Explorer/Edge are suspected  not to be not usable.

The question arrow to W3C remains: why `<TABLE>` does not have some simple attributes like `scroll-x scroll-y` for an easy, correct, and expectable result (fixed header, footer, and first column if used or asked) included yet?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal solution, just in case someone wants a quick answer.

All you need is a scrolling `div` wrapper and on the `th` element,  `position: sticky;` to the top and a background. That's it

```css
th {
  background: aquamarine;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

.table-wrapper {
  border: solid 1px black;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Header1</th>
          <th>Header2</th>
          <th>Some other Header</th>
          <th>Header3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Here's a working jsfiddle with the above solution but using divs and flexbox, not HTML tables: https://jsfiddle.net/nwb07yzL/1/