# how to scroll tbody while keeping table head fixed?

Tags: css

I have dynamically created bootstrap table and want to have my tbody scrollable while keeping head fixed but I am not able to do it. I want to do this with css.
As I am creating the table dynamically, it is different from creating table using html , as I am using jquery . I want answer according to my code as I am not able to apply other answers regarding these type of question.

Here is the code with less table content-

```js
var table = $("<table class='table'>");
table.append($("<thead><tr><th scope='col'>col1</th><th scope='col'>col2</th><th scope='col'>col3</th><th scope='col'>col4</th><th scope='col'>col5</th></tr><thead/>"));
for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
  var row = $('<tbody><tr class="parent_row" >' + '<td>' + "1" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "2" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "3" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td></tr><tbody/>');

  table.append(row);
  //child row
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr style="display: none">' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "4" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "5" + '</td></tr>');


    table.append(row);


    $("#table").html(table);
    $("#table").show();
    $('.parent_row').on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).closest('.parent_row').nextUntil('.parent_row').toggle();
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">

</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840074/how-to-stick-table-headerthead-on-top-while-scrolling-down-the-table-rows-with - does this answer your question?

Comment: You might need 2 tables where top table is for the heading and the bottom one is for scrolling.

Comment: can you explain me with the code? @XPD

Comment: @ConstantinGroß no this doesn't help?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723996/table-with-fixed-thead-and-scrollable-tbody

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stick table header(thead) on top while scrolling down the table rows with fixed header(navbar) in bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840074/how-to-stick-table-headerthead-on-top-while-scrolling-down-the-table-rows-with)

Comment: @Awais it not working, alignment problem is there and also scroll is not working properly, could you please tell me with the help of my code, it will be more helpful.

Comment: @AbhaySingh Posted my ans below (from your code)

Answer (score 0):

oveflow property does'nt apply to the tbody by default. To acheive that set display:block to tbody so that we can apply height and overflow to it. then set display:block to thead tr

```
tbody {
display:block;
overflow: auto;
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
}

thead tr {
display: block;
}
```

you can follow this link [here](https://medium.com/@vembarrajan/html-css-tricks-scroll-able-table-body-tbody-d23182ae0fbc)

Comment: @AbhaySingh follow the link which i have added to the answer. it may work for you

Answer (score 0):

Add these styles

```
#table {
    /* position: relative; */
    height: 100px; change height according to your need
    overflow: scroll;
    display: block;
}
#table .table>thead>tr>th {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Working Snippet

```js
var table = $("<table class='table'>");
table.append($("<thead><tr><th scope='col'>col1</th><th scope='col'>col2</th><th scope='col'>col3</th><th scope='col'>col4</th><th scope='col'>col5</th></tr><thead/>"));
for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
  var row = $('<tbody><tr class="parent_row" >' + '<td>' + "1" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "2" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "3" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td></tr><tbody/>');

  table.append(row);
  //child row
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr style="display: none">' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "4" + '</td>' + '<td>' + "5" + '</td></tr>');


    table.append(row);


    $("#table").html(table);
    $("#table").show();
    $('.parent_row').on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).closest('.parent_row').nextUntil('.parent_row').toggle();
    })
  }
}
```

```css
#table {
        /* position: relative; */
        height: 100px; 
        overflow: scroll;
        display: block;
    }
    #table .table>thead>tr>th {
        vertical-align: bottom;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 5;
        background: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">

</table>
```