# Fixed table head & left column(s) - how to keep header always on top (z-index)

Tags: javascript, html, css

for a long time, I'm trying to prepare table with fixed header + fixed left columns. Now I'm near to the finish, but there is one last thing. Left column is scrolling over the header, although header have bigger z-index.

```
 thead, thead > tr, thead > tr > th {z-index:1 !important;}
 tbody, tbody > tr, tbody > tr > td {z-index:0 !important;}
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xesopj1f/5/
Just scroll down the table. Do you have a sense, what I'm still missing there? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798357/using-translatey-on-thead-and-tbody-messes-up-z-index

Comment: OK, thanks, it was about add $(this).find("thead").appendTo($(this).find("table")); to javascript section